# REGEX: How to capture a certain string of numbers using regex but not when the sting is in the text of a URL?

Tags: regex, string, url, boost

I have been trying to figure out a regex for this problem for quite some time, but it has not worked out, so I am reaching out for some help.
I have created a regex that will capture a particular string of numbers when they appear in an email. The problem is that it also captures this particular string of numbers when they are inside a URL. The URLs are randomly generated, and a great deal of the time, they contain a string of numbers that matches my regex. I've been trying to create a regex that will still capture a particular string of numbers but will ignore that string when it is inside a URL but with no luck. Here is an example of the regex I have been using.

```
    (?:700[0-9][0-9]{7}|81[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}|9999[0-9]{8})\b
```

and here is an example of an email that contains that certain string.

> https://test.test.test.outlook.com/?url=bunchofrandomstuffthatdoesnotmatterF&data=sfsfsdagfd4454366474retre45435700000000%7CRegex%randomthingsoiMC4wLjAwnotareallink2luMzIiLCJBTiIjfsdkljafdslflsdkajfljie
>
> mailto: From:  Sent: Monday, May 17, 2021 11:42 AM To: 700000000 . If received"
> Detected: External recipients,
>
> https://test.test.test.outlook.com/?url=bunchofrandomstuffthatdoesnotmatterF&data=sfsfsdagfd4454366474retre45435700000000%7CRegex%randomthingsoiMC4wLjAwnotareallink2luMzIiLCJBTiIjfsdkljafdslflsdkajfljie

The problem is that it is capturing the number in text that makes up the  URLs and the number in the mailto line. If possible, I need a regex that captures the string of numbers that meet the criteria of the regex anywhere in the email except for when it is inside of a URL.

I have tried the following

> (?:700[0-9][0-9]{7}|81[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}|9999[0-9]{8})\b(?:(?!https://test.test.test.outlook.com).)

It does not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Try it like this `https?://\S*(?:700[0-9][0-9]{7}|81[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}|9999[0-9]{8})\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:700[0-9][0-9]{7}|81[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}|9999[0-9]{8})\b` https://regex101.com/r/rv29Tt/1

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is much better than what I've been trying to do. The only thing is that when I try to copy that into a new regex101 it complains about the / saying an unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash.  I can't figure don't know why as I have tried my best to make all of the settings the same.

Comment: Did it work out in the code? On regex101 at the left top you can change the delimiter to an other one than `/` You can also escape the forward slash like https://regex101.com/r/VzCe9b/1

Comment: Yes, the code worked and I would like to consider this question answered. Thank you for the help. How do you get credit for answering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) supports Perl Regular Expression Syntax, from which you can leverage backtracking control verbs [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

As the url is randomly generated, instead of excluding `https://test.test.test.outlook.com` you can match `http://` or `https://` followed by 0 or more non whitespace chars using `\S*` to rule out matching an url.

Then you can use the same pattern after the alternation `|`

**Note** that for the current example data, the pattern in the question does not match. I have added 2 zeroes to `700000000` to get a match in the example data.

```
\bhttps?://\S*(?:700[0-9][0-9]{7}|81[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}|9999[0-9]{8})\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:700[0-9][0-9]{7}|81[0-9][0-9][0-9]{5}|9999[0-9]{8})\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/th7xqj/1).

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again but are there any alternatives to (*SKIP)(*FAIL) the reason I ask is that Microsoft does not validate those verbs despite them saying that they use boost for regex.

Comment: In that case you can match the first part and instead of using skip fail you can use a capture group.

Comment: I know this is old, I just wanted to say that code with the (*SKIP)(*FAIL) was not working for me at the time but a few months later it started to work with Microsoft. Thanks once again for the help.